# Trigonometric Identities and Fourier Series

Tags: trigonometry, fourier-series

I have the series:

$$2+\sum_{m=1}^n 4(-1)^m\cos(m\pi x)$$

Here, $x\in (-1,1)$.

I need to show that this equals some fraction with only cosine terms and $n$ (no $m$).

Just looking for some pointers on where to start as I haven't the faintest clue!

Comment: You can find some good starting points on how to format mathematics on the site [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020). [This AMS reference](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf) is very useful.

Comment: @mrf Isn't a trigonometric polynomial a Fourier series? I admit I did not know this convention.

Comment: @julien (It is, after padding with infinitely many zeros, but the question isn't really about Fourier series. I removed the comment anyway, since two of you alread posted the same hint.)

Comment: This trigonometric expression in even, so its Fourier series has no sine terms.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:
$$
(-1)^m\cos(m\pi x)=\frac{e^{im\pi (x+1)}+e^{-im\pi (x+1)}}{2}=\frac{z^m+z^{-m}}{2}
$$
where $z\neq 1\neq z^{-1}$.

Comment: Sorry, what was the geometric sum that you had written before editing your comment?

Comment: @Sapph $\sum_{m=1}^nr^m=(r^{n+1}-r)/(r-1)$ when $r\neq 1$. And it is equal to $n$ when $r=1$.

Comment: Actually, the condition $x\in(-1,1)$ is useful for it implies $z=e^{i\pi(x+1)}\neq 1\neq z^{-1}$. Now you have everything you need to understand rlgordonma's detailed answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use

$$\cos{(m \pi x)} = \Re{[e^{i m \pi x}]}$$

and evaluate the subsequent geometrical series.

$$\begin{align}\sum_{m=1}^{n} (-1)^m e^{i m \pi x}&= \frac{e^{i \pi (x+1)}-e^{i \pi (n+1) (x+1)}}{1+e^{i \pi x}}\\\end{align}$$

Take real parts:

$$\implies \sum_{m=1}^{n} (-1)^m \cos{(\pi m x)}  = -\frac{1}{2} + (-1)^n \frac{\cos{[(n+1/2) \pi x]}}{\cos{(\pi x/2)}}$$

$$2+\sum_{m=1}^n 4(-1)^m\cos(m\pi x) = (-1)^n \frac{4 \cos{[(n+1/2) \pi x]}}{\cos{(\pi x/2)}}$$

Comment: Hello. The sum is finite.

Comment: Also: your infinite sum is divergent. (The terms don't tend to zero.)

Comment: My mistake...really hitting the jackpot here!

Comment: @rlgordonma Thank you!!

Comment: Sorry to bother you Ron, but I still don't understand this after working on it on and off for a few days! Wondering if you can help. I get that $
(-1)^m\cos(m\pi x)=\frac{e^{im\pi (x+1)}+e^{-im\pi (x+1)}}{2}$, by saying $(-1)^m=\cos(m\pi)$ but I'm unsure of how to evaluate this to get what you did. And then also how to evaluate the real parts. Any tips?